# Is is possible to create a custom messenger bot on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, bots, facebook-messenger

I would like to know that we are having a lead generation campaign running on Facebook but few of the times our staff isn't available to answer the query on Facebook messenger, so based on that short-coming I am thinking to devise a mechanism that **"If within 1 hour of user's message no one replies to him then an automated BOT message should get sent to him."**

Please don't deprecate this question as it is based entirely on knowledge. And if perhaps someone has hints or links on how to achieve this thing then I will really appreciate it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some options:

1. You can query your `/conversations` edge every X minutes to detect when there is a message from a user which has not been replied to, then you would send the automated message using Send API.
   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v10.0/conversation
   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/send-api/
2. You can use webhook data for incoming messages to create a task that will run at `received_time + 60 minutes`, find the thread in your conversations edge based on PSID and then check if there has been a reply
3. Alternatively you can check out Handover Protocol which allows a Page to simultaneously use a Messenger Bot and Live chat agent to handle messaging
   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/handover-protocol/